# Полоса прокрутки в iframe

Tags: html, c#, css, html5, asp.net

На *ASP.NET* не получается убрать полосу прокрутки в `iframe` ниже код:

```
<div>
     <iframe src="../Help/HelpDesk.aspx" width="650" height="360" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

пробовал через `CSS` но тоже не могло, подскажите как решить эту проблему.

В общем проблему нашёл. На странице `HelpDesk.aspx` открывается PDF файл на странице а в нём уже прокрутка. Открывается так: код C# `Response.Redirect("1.pdf");` из этого следует вопрос как сделать что бы он его открыл без прокрутки?

Comment: Хорошо бы было знать код `HelpDesk.aspx`, то как там внедрен PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Отображается плагин Adobe Reader'а, который показывает скролл внутри себя.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо я нашёл решения. Написал конвертер из Текста в HTML